# Rest to make call to another process just once in entire life cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

say Rest service got one request which is giving a call to another service (email service), 
but when Rest service got another request which is giving a call to email service I want it to skip that step.

also rest service should be intelligent enough to see if email process is being running or stopped if stopped any next request to rest service is allowed to call email service.

Rest Method : -

```
void SaveDataAndCallEmailService(Data data)
{
     cntx.Add(data);
     cntx.SaveChanges();

     SendEmail();
}
```

now my query is how to make "SendMail()" method to be called only once only if Email Process is not running.

for e.g. : -

```
void SaveDataAndCallEmailService(Data data)
{
     cntx.Add(data);
     cntx.SaveChanges();

     if(!EmailProcessIsRunning)
       SendEmail();

     EmailProcessIsRunning= true;
}
```

**Edit: -**

Now, here "EmailProcessIsRunning" is always false, even though I marked it as true.

When server receive second request I found "EmailProcessIsRunning" is false again.

How to persist it's value?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample `EmailProcessIsRunning` is not defined anywhere. Makes if more difficult to see if there's a scope issue.

Assuming there's no scope issues, if you want to persist the value saved to `EmailProcessIsRunning` between requests of on a stateless webapi server you'll need to add a DependecyResolver to your server. Read this for more information http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

edit: (a simpler answer)

You can add a static property to your class, and set it to true when the process is started.

e.g.

`public bool static EmailProcessIsRunning { get; set; }`

Comment: Well yes the issue is I would like to persist the value saved to "EmailProcessIsRunning" between requests but cannot add dependencyResolver